# iOS & Obj-C Strange formatted string to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

I have a date string like this: 2015-09-06T06:00:00

And I'm trying to convert it to NSDate with this function:

```
+(NSDate*)dateStringToNSDate:(NSString*)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

And it's a nil for me? Where am I doing the mistake? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is wrong. That's the problem.

Try this one. Should fix it

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: This was fixed my problem but, why? (I'm looking at all my old questions. Now, I see that this is weird.)

Comment: The T represents the delimiter for the time but it’s actually not part of the format. That’s why you have to enclose it using the apostrophes. See as ref, especially “Fixed Formats”: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.